# Know the position of the mouse for the event onmousemove in IE 9, firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I use this function to obtain the position of the mouse for the event `onmousemove`, but get a different result in Internet Explorer 9.

```
function mouseCoords(ev){
if(ev.pageX || ev.pageY){
    return {x:ev.pageX, y:ev.pageY};
}
return {
    x:ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft - document.body.clientLeft,
    y:ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop  - document.body.clientTop
};
}
```

What is the function for the majority of browsers?

Answer (score 1):

The most consistent way to track the mouse coordinates across browsers is to use jQuery.
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Comment: How i will pass the event (ev) to the jquery, in my own javascript file?